# How exactly does Shield Master work?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, shield, two-weapon-fighting

Does Shield Master removing shields' two-weapon fighting penalties mean I don't take any penalties when dual wielding shields, even if I don't have the Two Weapon Fighting feat? I plan on getting Shield Master through the Weapon and Shield ranger combat style (gained as a slayer talent), so I won't have to meet its requirements.

e.g. If I have normally a +10 Attack Bonus, and I wielded a Kukri (primary) and Heavy Shield (secondary):

Normal: +4/+0

TWF: +6/+6

ShieldMaster(no TWF): +4/+10

ShieldMaster(TWF): +6/+10

So then if I wielded TWO Heavy Shields:

Normal: Same

TWF: Same

ShieldMaster(no TWF): +10/+10

ShieldMaster(TWF): +10/+10

Is my logic right here (e.g. Shield Master when using Dual-Shields makes Two-Weapon Fighting not needed? Or does Shield Master do less than that)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, when using the two-weapon fighting combat option, the Shield Master feat means any attacks you make with a shield are made at no penalty. Since all of your attacks are made with a shield, none of them are penalized. The Two-Weapon Fighting feat is irrelevant, since all that does is reduce those penalties, while Shield Master eliminates them.

Note that, normally, Shield Master also *requires* the Two-Weapon Fighting feat. That means you cannot use Shield Master without the Two-Weapon Fighting feat, as feats’ requirements must be met in order to use them.

But if you use a slayer talent to get a ranger combat style, and choose from the “weapon and shield” combat style in order to get Shield Master without meeting its prerequisites, then yes, you get to skip the Two-Weapon Fighting feat, and it won’t matter since all it does is reduce the penalties that you’re ignoring. Note that this approach does prevent you from taking Improved Two-Weapon Fighting and Greater Two-Weapon Fighting, which could be painful. You’ll have to think long and hard about whether or not it’s worth it to burn two or three feats on one or two extra attacks at low attack bonuses.

Comment: I would also question the fact that second shield is not a **weapon** until you make an attack with it, so it won't qualify for feat requirements as "another weapon".

Comment: @Draco-S Shields are both weapons and protective gear. They are not “temporarily a weapon” while bashing, they just are weapons. See [here are their weapon descriptions](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/weapons/weapon-descriptions/shield-heavy-or-light/).

Comment: "You can bash an opponent with a shield, using it as an *off-hand* weapon." That implies that you can't use shield as a primary weapon.

Comment: @Draco-S That line was [removed by errata](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/47918/4563), and [honestly was always a description, not a proscription, anyway](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/47919/4563).

Comment: @KRyan What if I'm playing a Slayer, and I used the Ranger Combat Style to take Shield Master at level 6 while ignoring the Pre-reqs? Then can I fully get away with not taking Two-Weapon Fighting?

Comment: Ok, that makes sense now.

Comment: @PaulCline Aha, yes, that’s exactly what I was referring to in my footnote. I’ll expand since now I see that it does apply for you.

Comment: Ok that makes sense now Thanks! Now I just have to figure out how to make a decent build with Dual Shields haha!

Comment: @PaulCline Can you use D&D 3.5e content, or only Pathfinder content? I made a 3.PF dual-shield character a while back and might have some ideas. The dungeoncrasher fighter option from *Dungeonscape* is phenomenal when combined with Shield Slam. Parrying Shield from *Lords of Madness* is also a really great option when you have a high-AC shield.

Comment: @KRyan I can use pathfinder and only: Core Rules, Advanced Player Guide, Advanced Classes, Ultimate Equipment/Combat/Magic, and Dirty Tactics Toolbox! Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: @PaulCline That will take more work to figure out; I only mentioned the 3.5e material because I had a lot of details already worked out for a past character. For help here, you’ll have to ask a new question. Please [read our advice on character-build questions, it will help you successfully get useful answers](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8123/4563). (It’s technically about D&D 5e, but the principles remain the same.)

Comment: @KRyan Ok Thank you for all the help! I'll get together what info/ideas I have for the character, read the guide at the link you posted, then ask for advice on here when ready!

Comment: @KRyan ok I made a new question as suggested: 

https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/139709/51654

Comment: @PaulCline I saw, and voted to reopen it. Since no one’s saying anything, it’s not precisely clear to me what people want to see from it, but I can tell you it’s at 4/5 votes for reopening, so hopefully that will happen soon.

Comment: @KRyan ok thanks for the update. I've minimized it as much as I can..not sure how to make it less broad and I followed the Guidelines you linked best I could. I'll wait and hope for the best haha.